# PHP парсинг XML param в yandex.xml

Tags: php, simplexml

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как прочитать и вывести данные из файла XML?
Есть файл стандарта yandex

```
<yml_catalog date='******'>
<shop>

<categories>
<category id='34'>Аккумуляторы</category>
.......
</categories>
<offers>
<offer id='1' type='vendor.model' available='false'>
....
<name>Аккумулятор 1</name>
....
<param name='Напряжение' unit='В'>12.00</param>
<param name='Ёмкость' unit='Ач'>2.40</param>
<param name='Тип (технология)'>Ni-Cd </param>
<param name='Время зарядки' unit='мин'>60.00</param>
<param name='Вес' unit='кг'>0.32</param>
<param name='Комплектация'></param>
</offer>

<offer id='2' type='vendor.model' available='false'>
....
<name>Аккумулятор 2</name>
....
<param name='Напряжение2' unit='В'>442.00</param>
<param name='Ёмкость2' unit='Ач'>42.40</param>
<param name='Тип (технология)2'>Ni-Cd </param>
<param name='Время зарядки2' unit='мин'>260.00</param>
<param name='Вес2' unit='кг'>20.32</param>
<param name='Комплектация2'>dsadsdd</param>
</offer>
</offers>
</shop>
```

У меня уже есть цикл чтения всех данных, кроме param. Как оформить чтение именно param равному каждому офферу?

Делал так

```
foreach ($offers->shop->offers->offer[0]->param as $param) {
$chname=$param['name'];
$chunit=$param["unit"];
$chdigits=$param;
}
```

но оно не идет по циклу всего файла, а выводит постоянно только первый блок параметров (повторяет одно и тоже) и в поселедующих "offer id"...

Так:

```
Аккумулятор1
  -парам1
  -парам1
  -парам1
Аккумулятор2
  -парам1
  -парам1
  -парам1
```

Как эот реализовать, чтобы возможно как-то с верхнего уровня передавался идентификатор where id=1, id=2 и так далее? Или другие способы перепрыгивать и выводить правильно.. Но не нашел, как ставить условие.

Чтоб было так:

```
Аккумулятор1
  -парам1
  -парам1
  -парам1
Аккумулятор2
  -парам2
  -парам2
  -парам2
```

Comment: Так вы в цикле каждый раз переписывание переменные.

Comment: Так вот а как сделать, чтоб оно в цикле читало только все param. Если б одно значение было, то понятно.. а вот как его чтоб по одному офферу проходить? эти <param name='Напряжение2' unit='В'> не повторяются, могут быть различные новые имена name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, нашел ответ.
Первый цикл значений у меня был такой

```
foreach ( $offers->shop->offers->offer as $offer ) :
```

Для вывода param просто

```
foreach ($offer->param as $param) {
```

) и работает. Спасибо за Naumov за коммент)